# any chance to define custom highlighting for certain text

Tags: phpstorm

I'm extensively using debug level logging like that:

```
Log::instance()->add($this->debugLogLevel, "\nTransaction is started");
```

What I don't like is that it interferes with real code. Is there any way to define custom highlighting for these pieces of code (like for example for comments)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no such option.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-1561

Comment: Hey, thanks) You seem to be the only one giving me the answers about PHP storm and most of them are about the impossibility of what I need :)

Comment: Maybe it's because you want some stuff that vast majority of users do not need/don't even think about such features? No demand = no implementation -- as simple as that. It's also not possible to include all possible (and not critical for development) features into an IDE while there are **specialised** solutions (widely) available.

Comment: As for this specific feature -- you could surround such code with custom collapsible region and hide it (collapse) by default. Problem is -- collapse-custom-region-by-default feature does not currently work .. and it seems that devs have no plans to resolve it in any nearest future: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17474 ; http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85517

Comment: Thanks) Do you know any other useful feature I could use which doesn't work? :)